# Ignition coil has discolored rings around it. Should it be replaced?

Tags: ignition-coil

My car (with 175k miles) has started to sputter occasionally while driving.  It happens briefly and lightly. It's almost as if the car is about to run out of gas and the engine is going to shut off.  The check engine light is not on.

I decided to replace the spark plugs. (I'm the second owner and unsure if they were ever changed.)

**While replacing the spark plugs, I noticed one of the ignition coils has two discolored bands around it. Is this okay to use or should it be replaced?**

[image: ignition coil]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, either a coil is going to work or it won't. Not for sure, but would assume the discoloration is due to heating and longevity of usage. This is internal heating of the coil, probably not heating from the engine. I don't think there is much to worry about with the coil without a misfire code. If you are worried about it, buy a spare. I doubt they are very expensive. If not, just change them out as a maintenance item.